# $A=\{{1\over Z}: Z\in \mathbb{C},|Z|=2\}$ Is it represents Circle?

Tags: complex-numbers

$A=\{{1\over Z}: Z\in \mathbb{C},|Z|=2\}$ is it represents circle?

My attempt: If $|Z|=|x+iy|=2\\ \implies x^2+y^2=4\\ then \ \ {1\over Z}={x-iy\over x^2+y^2}= {x\over 4}+i{y\over4}$ how can we say this represents circle?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All points which satisfy $|z|=2$ lie on a circle around the origin with radius $2$. If you take $1/z$ instead then you have $|1/z|=1/2$, so you get a circle of radius $1/2$.

The function $z \mapsto 1/z$ induces a bijection between the points of the circle around the origin with radius $2$ and the points of the circle around the origin with radius $1/2$. The map is its own inverse, so it also works in the other direction with the same map.

Comment: What if $A=\{{1\over Z}: Z\in \mathbb{C},|Z-1|=2\}$ would it also make circle?

Comment: @Chris Sure, since it's a moebius transforms and the image is compact.

Comment: Can I say like this $|{1\over Z}| \le |{1\over Z-1 }| ={1\over 2}$, that's why it's a circle.

Comment: @Chris Nope, not every set whose inverse is bounded is a circle. Further it's wrong to say $|1/z| \le 1/(z+1)$. Consider small numbers to see that!